# Nebular: nb-datepicker does not detect date changes when used inside nb-tabset in a nbPopover

Tags: angular, date, tabs, popup, nebular

I'm trying to use nb-datepicker inside an nbPopover with nb-tabset, unfortunately the date changes are not detected. The same code with only nb-datepicker and nb-tabset works fine in the main page, but when used in an nbPopover, the (dateChange) method does not work anymore. I don't know if I missed something, if it's a bug or a feature not yet available in Nebular. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<button nbButton [nbPopover]="tabs" nbPopoverTrigger="click">Test</button>
<ng-template #tabs>
  <nb-tabset>
     <nb-tab tabTitle="tab">
       <input nbInput [ngModel]='start_date' [nbDatepicker]="startDateTimePicker">
       <nb-datepicker #startDateTimePicker format="yyyy/MM/dd" (dateChange)="onStartDateChanged($event)">
       </nb-datepicker>
     </nb-tab>
  </nb-tabset>
</ng-template>
```